# "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Pretty sure I know why I'm getting the error, just not sure how to go about fixing it. In a FormView ItemTemplate I've got a Label control for the Project ID# bound to the FormView's SQLDatasource. I've also got a DropDownList whose SQLDatasource I've got tied to the Label.Text as a ControlParameter. I am guessing since the Label control isn't bound yet, that's causing my DDL to kick out that error.

ASPX

```
<asp:FormView ID="FvChangeOrder" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProjectChangeOrderID"
    DataSourceID="FvChangeOrderSQL" OnItemCommand="FvChangeOrder_OnItemCommand"
    OnDataBound="FvChangeOrder_OnDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>Project #: </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="LblProjectID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectID") %>' /></div>
        <div>Shipment #: </div>
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DdlShipment" DataSourceID="DdlShipmentSQL"
                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProjectShipmentID") %>' DataValueField="ProjectShipmentID"
                DataTextField="ShipmentNo" Enabled="False" />
        </div>
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FvChangeOrderSQL" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectLogicTestConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [ProjectID], [ProjectChangeOrderID], [ProjectShipmentID], [SeqNo], 
    [Date], [EnteredBy_UserID], [Source], [Initiator], [Reason], [ReasonNotes], 
    [ApprovalCode], [Description], [NumPanels], [Amount], [IsCommissionable], [DateDue], 
    [DateRecd], [Status]
FROM [tblProjectChangeOrder] WHERE ([ProjectChangeOrderID] = @PCOID)">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PCOID" QueryStringField="PCOID" Type="Int32"/>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DdlShipmentSQL" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectLogicTestConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT pco.ProjectShipmentID, ps.ShipmentNo FROM tblProjectChangeOrder pco
LEFT JOIN tblProjectShipment ps ON pco.ProjectShipmentID = ps.ProjectShipmentID 
WHERE pco.ProjectID = @ProjectID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FvChangeOrder$LblProjectID" 
        Name="ProjectID" PropertyName="Text"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Would I be better off leaving out the WHERE and ControlParameter on the DDL SQLDatasource and changing the DDL's SQL Source in codebehind on the OnDataBound method of the FormView?

Comment: Tested your code. With `Eval` and `Bind` (after first changing to Eval without testing Bind). It works both times.

Comment: So it's not the Bind/Eval on the DDL.SelectedValue that's causing the problem...

Comment: It would seem so. But I did remove the `SelectParameters` for testing, maybe in there lies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it worked out. I changed the ControlParameter to just Parameter Type="String" and on Form_Load set a Label to FvChangeOrder.FindControl("LblProjectID"), assigned LblProject.Text to a string, then passed that as the DefaultValue for the Select Parameter.

On an semi-related problem I had to remove the SelectedValue on the markup side and handle SQLCommand in the Form_Load for the DDL SelectedValue. Probably a bad dataset but I kept getting an error that the value in the field wasn't in the List or something like that. There are multiple Change Orders for a given project that have NULL values for the ShippingID.

Anywho, all is working on the ItemTemplate side. Now to see if I can keep everything working on the EditItemTemplate. :P